# Strange results for attribute usage in Decision Tree with caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, r-caret, c5.0

I want to know what variables are important in my decision tree model.

I got the model by using train() of caret package.
But the results for attribute usage are strange for fator variables.

Below is my code.

```r
set.seed(123)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary)
mDt <- train(metS ~ ., data= df_train, method = "C5.0", metric="ROC", trControl = ctrl); mDt
```

I got the attribute usage by using C5imp(). (The results by using summary(mDt) were the same.)

```
C5imp(mDt$finalModel)
```

The attribute usage results are as follows:

- age 100.00
- BMI 100.00
- height 100.00
- weight 100.00
- job7 98.90
- piHeatScore 83.81
- dailyAlcoholIntake_final 82.96
- pi4.L 67.14
- familyIncome^9
- pi17.C 60.33
- pi6.C 59.72
- pi13.L 56.53
- ...

The strange thing is that one factor variable (e.g. 'pi4': Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4"<"5") has multiple attribute usages. (e.g. 'pi4.L', 'pi4.Q', 'pi4.C', 'pi^4')

It's similar for unordered factors. For example, 'marriage' is a factor w/ 6 levels ("1","2","3","4","5","6"), and the attribute usages are shown for 'marriage2', 'marriage3', 'marriage4', 'marriage5', and 'marriage6'.

However, the results should be like the following:

(The results below were obtained by using C5.0() with same data. One attribute usage is shown for one factor variable.)

```
mTemp <- C5.0(df_train[,-1], df_train$metS) 
C5imp(mTemp)
```

- BMI   100.00
- age   32.37
- pi6   27.28
- pi13  16.92
- pi9   15.76
- job   9.07
- pi14  2.88
- ...

I think this is caused by a difference when applying C5.0 method by C5.0() and train().

I want to use train() of caret package, because it automatically applys cross validation etc.

Please help me.

Comment: I found the answer myself :) This problem has been solved when I changed the method of inputting arguments of train() from formula to x and y. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135671/how-does-caret-handle-factors